# Reference to css in an html page in a VStudio MVC 5 app not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a weird css issue.
(probably missed something really basic).
I have a small project (one of 8 in my solution).
It is an MVC empty application, with a simple index.html file, which references bootstrap.css
It also has a popup. (which does not reference any css at all).
The popup shows the expected css styles, but it does not reference them at all. (Left to it's parent's css links).
But the **index.html** ..looks nothing like it should (using navbar navbar-inverse).
What have I missed? please.
  I used nm to install the necessary, hence the folder structure.

(The js refs are being picked up).

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JS Application</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/oidc-client/dist/oidc-client.js"></script>

<style>
    .main-container {
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="vertical-align:top;">
<nav id="main_nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-inverse" style="color:gainsboro;height:100%">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JS Application</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container main-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled requests">
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Home</a></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-login">Login</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-call-api">Call API</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-logout">Logout</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is an image of the project's  solution explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for an Empty non MVC website in Visual Studio is to show All Files, find the Content folder, then include it in the project, add the css files e.g. bootstrap via NuGet, if not already there (VS usually for most templates adds it in automatically), but in a blank asp.net website, the Content Folder may not be included/visible.
Set your href to the css file and all's done and working.